# Why does soup.findAll return []?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having trouble reading data from a url with BeautifulSoup

This is my code:

```
url1 = "https://www.barstoolsportsbook.com/events/1018282280"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"section"})
print(data)
#for x in data:
#    print(x.find('p').text)
```

When I print(data) I am returned []. What could be the reason for this? I would like to avoid using selenium for this task if possible.

This is the HTML for what I'm trying to grab

```
<div data-v-50e01018="" data-v-2a52296d="" class="section"><p data-v-5f665d29="" data-v-50e01018="" class="header strongbody2">HOT TIPS</p><p data-v-5f665d29="" data-v-50e01018="" class="tip body2"> The Mets have led after 3 innings in seven of their last nine night games against NL East Division opponents that held a losing record. </p><p data-v-5f665d29="" data-v-50e01018="" class="tip body2"> The 'Inning 1 UNDER 0.5 runs' market has hit in each of the Marlins' last nine games against NL East opponents. </p></div>
```

Comment: The data is loaded via scripts. You'll need a webdriver like selenium. What data are you after specifically? You may have better luck calling the API.

Comment: Not your issue, but best practice, I would define url1 under your imports.

Comment: dang, was hoping to avoid selenium. there's an api call i can use? @1extralime

Comment: Sure depending on what specific data you're after. Its usually a quick less intense way to get data.

Comment: The page is loaded by a GET request to an API. Example: https://eu-offering.kambicdn.org/offering/v2018/pivuspa/betoffer/event/1018282280.json?type=&range_start=0&range_size=1&includeParticipants=true&lang=en_US&market=US So as mentioned above, you'll need to use Selenium. Or, you may be able to use requests to query the API directly.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I use that link above to grab things like ML, O/U - wasn't aware that I could grab the Hot Tips data that I'm after (@1extralime) - i'll have to look into that and see if I can find where it is - cool stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely get what you want with this request:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Authorization': 'Basic MTI2OWJlMjItNDI2My01MTI1LWJlNzMtMDZmMjlmMmZjNWM3Omk5Zm9jajRJQkZwMUJjVUc0NGt2S2ZpWEpremVKZVpZ',
    'Origin': 'https://www.barstoolsportsbook.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.barstoolsportsbook.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.isportgenius.com.au/preview/1018282280', headers=headers)
response.json()
```

You should browse the network tab to see where the rest of the data is coming from, or use a webdriver.

Comment: This is absolutely right, thank you.
I would not have thought to do that

Comment: As a note, I would add that the Authorization Header key may change over time, in which case you can just look at the network tab at the request details to see the new one.